# Custom Screener on Trading View Pine Script for a List of Symbols

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

I am a beginner in Pine scripting. I am trying to create a custom screener and alerts for a fixed list of 25 Symbols.

The screener would scan the symbols from the list where a 15minute candle close is higher than Pivot.

I am unable to figure out a way to get the value for previous day high, low, close dynamically for the fixed list of symbols.

I tried with security(syminfo.tickerid,'D',high) but **syminfo.tickerid would mean its specific for the chart that is currently displayed**.

Can you please help ?

The calculation of current day pivot level is based on :

pivot = (Previous Day High + Previous Day Low + Previous Day Close)/3.

```
higherTF = input.timeframe("D") 
prevCloseHTF = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) 
prevHighHTF = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) 
prevLowHTF = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, low[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)  
pivot = ( prevHighHTF[1] + prevLowHTF[1] + prevCloseHTF[1] ) / 3

customFunc() => close > pivot  // The close should be the current 15minute candle close

s1  = security('BTCUSD', timeframe.period, customFunc())
s2  = security('ETHUSD', timeframe.period, customFunc())
s3  = security('XRPUSD', timeframe.period, customFunc())
s4  = security('LTCUSD', timeframe.period, customFunc())
s5  = security('USDTUSD', timeframe.period, customFunc())

scr_label = 'Pivot Screener: \n##########\n'

scr_label := s1  ? scr_label + 'BTCUSD\n'  : scr_label
scr_label := s2  ? scr_label + 'ETHUSD\n'  : scr_label
scr_label := s3  ? scr_label + 'XRPUSD\n'  : scr_label
scr_label := s4  ? scr_label + 'LTCUSD\n'  : scr_label
scr_label := s5  ? scr_label + 'USDTUSD\n' : scr_label

alert_message = "Above Pivot : " + scr_label + "\n\n"

// Send an alert
alert(alert_message, freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar_close )
```

Unfortunately I dont know how to run the customFunc() for these 5 fixed symbols that calculates the pivot information dynamically.

I had implemented a similar alert system in another tool. The concept is the same.

There is fixed list of symbols that get screened with the below condition. If it is true then I get an alert.

**15min close** above Daily Pivot Alert Example:

[Example of the strategy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCsqn.png)

Comment: So, you need help in writing the `pivot` calculation?

Comment: Yes @BarisYakut ,

I need to use the pivot formula pivot = (Previous Day High + Previous Day Low + Previous Day Close)/3 and to make sure that it calculates for all the fixed list of Symbols.

This way when a 15minute candle is above the pivot level then I would get an alert.

Comment: @BarisYakut 

I had implemented a similar alert system in another tool. The concept is the same. I am unable to add an image in the comment. Please find the attached image in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [History reference operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator) to refer to historical data. For example, `close[2]` will return the close value of two bars ago.

So, your pivot calculation should be:

```
pivot = (high[1] + low[1] + close[1])/3
```

Then use this variable in your `security()` calls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

So for eg. 
``higherTF = input.timeframe("D")
prevCloseHTF = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
prevHighHTF = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
prevLowHTF = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, low[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)``

Here syminfo.tickerid would mean specific to one chart that is on TV display. 
But I need the screener to run for a fixed predefined list of symbols. Continued...

Comment: `higherTF = input.timeframe("D")
prevCloseHTF = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, close[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
prevHighHTF = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
prevLowHTF = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, higherTF, low[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

pivot = ( prevHighHTF[1] + prevLowHTF[1] + prevCloseHTF[1] ) / 3

customFunc() => close > pivot  // The close should be the current 15minute candle close. `
Is this right ?

Continued....

Comment: `s1  = security('BTCUSD', timeframe.period, customFunc())
s2  = security('ETHUSD', timeframe.period, customFunc())
s3  = security('XRPUSD', timeframe.period, customFunc())
s4  = security('LTCUSD', timeframe.period, customFunc())
s5  = security('USDTUSD', timeframe.period, customFunc())`

Unfortunately I dont know how to process these 5 fixed symbols and not based on TV chart on display

Comment: Please edit your original question and state your question or what's not clear again. It is hard to read code in comments.

Comment: I have updated the original question. I hope its fine now.